# Checking model is null or not in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to check the model is null OR not but I am not able to solve the issue. 
While rendering the main view I have rendered the partial view as follows

**Main View**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="surveyPreviewModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="surveyPreviewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-lg modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="surveyPreviewContent">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="surveyPreviewLabel">Survey Preview</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="surveyPreviewBody">
                @Html.Partial("_surveyPreview")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in partial view I have function as below

```
@model LMS_TraineeSurveyPaginationViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">

function SurveyPreview(){
var surveyQuestionViewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.SurveyQuestionsViewModel.ToArray()));
var surveyQuestionOptionChoideViewModel= @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceViewModel.ToArray()));

$.post('@Url.Action("SurveyPreview", "Survey")', { SurveyID : surveyID,` page : page },
             function (data) {

                 $('#surveyPreviewBody').html('');
                 $('#surveyPreviewBody').html(data);

                 SetProgressBar(page,'@(Model==null?0: Model.Pager.TotalPages)');

             }).fail(function () {
                 alert("error in GetTraineeSurvey");
             }).success(function () {

             });         
}
</script>
```

So while rendering the partial view in this function(SurveyPreview) it is giving the error as model is null and straight away white screen shown. If I haven't called the function which is inside of partial view then why does it checking whether model is null OR not ? it should be whenever I execute function like on button click ?

I have a button on main view from where I am showing the bootstrap modal and on '`show`' method of bootstrap modal I am returning the same partial view again to bind the data in ajax call. 
Below code is written in partial view

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#surveyPreviewModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

            surveyID = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-surveyID');

            SurveyPreview(@SurveyPageTypePageNumber.StartPage,null);

        });

    })
```

and in controller

```
public ActionResult SurveyPreview(int SurveyID, int page)
{
   ------ some code ------
    return PartialView("_SurveyPreview",viewModel);
}
```

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: are you assigning an instance to `viewmodel` in the controller? i.e. `viewmodel = new viewmodel();`?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane Yes.. like this `var viewModel = new LMS_TraineeSurveyPaginationViewModel()
            {
                SurveyQuestionsViewModel = SurveyQuestionsViewModel.Where(x => x.PageNumber == pager.CurrentPage).ToList(),
                SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceViewModel = SurveyQuestionIDsOptionChoice,
                Pager = pager
            };`

Comment: Ok, and when you debug can you see the instance if you hover over `viewmodel` after it's created?

Comment: Yes.. definitely.. But the problem occurs initially when I am rendering the Main/parent view and on from that view rendering the partial. In this case action method is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you load Partial view using @Html.Partial("_surveyPreview") it required LMS_TraineeSurveyPaginationViewModel to be passed which are not supplied

so to call Partial view you need to write something like

```
@Html.Partial("_surveyPreview",new LMS_TraineeSurveyPaginationViewModel());
```

Comment: yeah.. tried this way and solved the issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The partial view expects a model of type `LMS_TraineeSurveyPaginationViewModel`. But you are not passing any model object when rendering partialview from the main view.

In partialview `function SurveyPreview()` uses Model's properties. Since you are not passing any model object from the main view, Model is coming null in the partial view. That's why you are seeing `NullReferenceException`.

So you need to make sure that the partial view gets model.

You need to take different approach to render the partial view. You can use `Html.Action` to call the Action method which will return the partial view and render in the main view.

Replace following line in your main view

```
@Html.Partial("_surveyPreview")
```

with

```
@Html.Action("SurveyPreview", new { SurveyID = "<<somesoveryId>>", page = "<<somepage>>"})
```

This way I will call `SurveyPreview` action of the controller with the provided parameters and it will return the partial view with model and it will be rendered.

I am not sure of the what values to be passed in `SurveyID` and `page` parameters so I have placed placeholders there. You need to put appropriate values over there.

Comment: Thanks for the help !